# Migration of content from WikkaWiki to MoinMoin

Tags: document-converter, moinmoin

I want to migrate all pages from [WikkaWiki](http://www.wikkawiki.org/HomePage) (MySQL) to [MoinMoin](http://moinmo.in/) (flat files).

Ideally, it would also keep the revision history for each page.
No need for ACLs, attachments, or users.

The wiki markup should either be converted to MoinMoin’s syntax (maybe in a second step, when all pages from WikkaWiki are exported as text files), or there should be a MoinMoin converter I could use to continue using WikkaWiki’s syntax.

I don’t have the programming knowledge to write this from scratch, but adjusting a script that comes close should be okay. If there is no tool doing this, maybe it’s possible by adding an intermediate step, e.g., WikkaWiki → MediaWiki → MoinMoin?